# How to read a specific word in a text file?

Tags: python

I am trying to make this program read a specific word in a text file, but the outcome only comes as "1". Why is this happening?

```
import os

openfile = input('Enter the input file: ')
accumulator = 0
entry = "PMID"
if os.path.isfile(openfile):
    file = open(openfile,'r')
    for entry in file.readlines():
        accumulator +=1
        print('there are:',accumulator)
        exit()

print('Input file not found.')
print('Please check the file name or the location of your input file.')
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: By doing `for entry in ...:` you are reassigning `entry` as the loop variable. You probably want something more like: `for line in file: if entry in line: ...`

Comment: there is `exit()` in your code!  you might want take that out!

Comment: You create a for loop that loops over the lines in the input file. You increase the counter by 1 print it and exit immediately. Basically, in the for-loop you assign new values to `entry` so the original constant is overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `exit()` inside your for loop. This means that after the first iteration (when `accumulator=1`), you are ending the loop. Move this instruction out of the loop for this to work properly.

```
import os

openfile = input('Enter the input file: ')
accumulator = 0
word = "PMID"

if os.path.isfile(openfile):
    file = open(openfile,'r')

    for entry in file.readlines():
        accumulator +=1

    print(f'There are {accumulator} occurences of "{word}" in {openfile}')

else:
  print('Input file not found.')
  print('Please check the file name or the location of your input
```

If you then want to count the occurences of a specific word...

```
import os

openfile = input('Enter the input file: ')
accumulator = 0
word = "PMID"

if os.path.isfile(openfile):
    file = open(openfile,'r')

    for entry in file.readlines():
        if word in entry:
            accumulator +=1

    print(f'There are {accumulator} occurences of "{word}" in {openfile}')

else:
  print('Input file not found.')
  print('Please check the file name or the location of your input file.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like:

```
for line in file:
    accumulator += entry in line

# This does not work if the entry occurs more than once on the same line.
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that note: very true if the goal is to count each word in a text file. Use with care ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to count how many times a certain word comes up we can use python's built-in str.count() function in order to do so. See documentation here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20count#str.count

Here is how it could be used in your case:

```
openfile = input('Enter the input file: ')  # Gets the input file from the user
word = 'PMID'  # The word we are trying to count

try:
    with open(openfile, 'r') as f:
    # Uses a context manager (the 'with' keyword) so that we do not need to manually close the file
        word_count = f.read().count(word)
        # Reads the entire file and then uses the built-in count() function to determine how many times the entry appears
        print(f'The word {word} appears {word_count} times.')
        quit()  # Exits the program
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Input file not found.')
    print('Please check the file name or the location of your input file.')
```

I hope this was what you were looking for!